# What is wrong with this statement? 'Unknown column'?

Tags: mysql-5.5, errors

I'm not used to the 'as' keyword and I thought it would be a nice idea to use it.
So why do I get an 'unknown column' (eid) error? I use mysql...

```
select t1.index as eid, t1.col1 as col1, t1.col2 as col2, 
t2.index, t2.col1, t2.col2,
t3.index, t3.col1, t3.col2 
from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t2.index=eid
left join table3 t3 on t3.index=eid;
```

The full statement is too long to present here without boring everybody. 
The column and table names are random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A relational sub-select is logically processed in the following sequence:

1. `FROM` clause
2. `WHERE` clause
3. `GROUP BY` clause
4. `HAVING` clause
5. `SELECT` clause
6. `ORDER BY` clause
7. `LIMIT...OFFSET` clause or the equivalent

Subsequently, the column labels defined in the `SELECT` clause are not yet known when the `FROM` clause, containing the joins in your example, is dealt with.