# Column or global variable ROWNUM not found

Tags: db2

I have made an attempt at the `ROW_NUMBER()`, and when exporting the results in a csv it was worked perfectly. The issue I’m having now is in the where clause to bring back records where `ROWNUM = 1`.

I am getting the error message:

> Column or global variable ROWNUM not found.

I have tried using `FETCH` to bring back one row; this works however the following join does not get considered.

Do you know what the best method is to bring back only records with `ROWNUM = 1`?

```
LEFT JOIN                                                           
(
    SELECT 
        CONO15, ACTR15, FLG115,  MEMB15 AS PAYOWNER, 
        PYTP15 AS PAYTYPE, PYRF15 AS PAYREF, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY MEMB15, PYTP15, PYRF15 
            ORDER BY  PYTP15 ASC) AS ROWNUM 
    FROM TKTDTA.PY015L1 
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1 
)C ON C.CONO15 = A.CONO09 AND C.PAYREF = A.PAYREF
```

Answer (score 4):

Lets see what we have here. Inside the parentheses we have a derived table (often called a subquery although this is a more general term), which is then aliased with the name `C`:

```
...                                                           
(
    SELECT 
        CONO15, ACTR15, FLG115,  MEMB15 AS PAYOWNER, 
        PYTP15 AS PAYTYPE, PYRF15 AS PAYREF, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY MEMB15, PYTP15, PYRF15 
            ORDER BY  PYTP15 ASC) AS ROWNUM 
    FROM TKTDTA.PY015L1 
    WHERE ROWNUM = 1 
) C  ...
```

Column `ROWNUM` is not a column of the base table (`PY015L1`) but defined in the `SELECT` clause. And there lies the problem. The logical processing of a query (and any subquery including a derived table) has a specific order which is (some parts not included):

```
FROM -> WHERE -> GROUP BY -> HAVING -> SELECT -> ORDER BY
```

So `WHERE` is before `SELECT` and cannot use any new columns defined there. That's the reason for the error.

You might ask? Isn't `ROWNUM` a real column? Haven't we just defined it?

Yes we did but it has a certain scope that can be used. `C` table is also a real table (it's just not a **base** table). We can use them **after** they has been defined, so `ROWNUM` can be used  in the following clauses (`ORDER BY` which is after `SELECT`) and **outside** the parentheses, wherever the `C` table can be used. Both table `C` and column `ROWNUM` are real tables and columns but only after they have been defined. It's like Pinocchio (*"See dad, I'm alive! And I'm a boy, I'm a **real** boy!"*). He is a real boy but only at the end of the story, after he has been transformed).

In your case, what is probably wanted is to remove the `WHERE ROWNUM = 1` and use the column in the following clauses, `ON` or `WHERE`. I'd guess the `ON` clause:

```
LEFT JOIN                                                           
(
    SELECT 
        CONO15, ACTR15, FLG115,  MEMB15 AS PAYOWNER, 
        PYTP15 AS PAYTYPE, PYRF15 AS PAYREF, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY MEMB15, PYTP15, PYRF15 
            ORDER BY  PYTP15 ASC) AS ROWNUM 
    FROM TKTDTA.PY015L1 
) C ON  C.CONO15 = A.CONO09 AND C.PAYREF = A.PAYREF  
    AND C.ROWNUM = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a subselect to build the rownum column and then filter it in the outer SELECT.

```
SELECT * 
 FROM (SELECT ... row_number() Over....as rownum)
WHERE rownum = 1
```

---

For additional background information, see:

[What is wrong with this statement? 'Unknown column'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76354/what-is-wrong-with-this-statement-unknown-column)